# React js I get error 404 with Stripe payment after deployment! why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I built an e-commerce as part of university project. Personally I had experience with web development but never with express js and Stripe so I had to learn everything from scratch in many points of this project.

The problem that I am facing is that the payment page fails to initialize but this happens only after deployment. I bought the domain name, and the website is already online on https://cyber-frog.co.uk/ and here is where I am facing the problem. If I use the application with "npm start" everything works well (of course changing the domain with localhost where is needed).

When looking at the console, I get thi error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**

And also, since I console.log the error message, I get this error too:

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**

Below I leave my code and I really hope someone will be able to help me because I am desperate as the deadline for this project is coming soon.

Here is the code of the file Checkout.js (frontend)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  CALCULATE_SUBTOTAL,
  CALCULATE_TOTAL_QUANTITY,
  selectCartItems,
  selectCartTotalAmount,
} from "../../redux/slice/cartSlice";
import { selectEmail } from "../../redux/slice/authSlice";
import {
  selectBillingAddress,
  selectShippingAddress,
} from "../../redux/slice/checkoutSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import CheckoutForm from "../../components/checkoutForm/CheckoutForm";
import styles from "./Checkout.module.scss";
import Card from "../../components/card/Card";
import { images } from "../../constants";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PK);

const Checkout = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(
    <img src={images.spinner} alt="Initializing Payment..." />
  );
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const totalAmount = useSelector(selectCartTotalAmount);
  const customerEmail = useSelector(selectEmail);

  const shippingAddress = useSelector(selectShippingAddress);
  const billingAddress = useSelector(selectBillingAddress);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(CALCULATE_SUBTOTAL());
    dispatch(CALCULATE_TOTAL_QUANTITY());
  }, [dispatch, cartItems]);

  const description = `Cyber Frog payment --> email: ${customerEmail}, Amount: ${totalAmount}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    // http://localhost:4242/payment
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("https://cyber-frog.co.uk/payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        items: cartItems,
        userEmail: customerEmail,
        shipping: shippingAddress,
        billing: billingAddress,
        description,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        return res.json().then((json) => Promise.reject(json));
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(
          <>
            <h4>Failed to initialize the payment!</h4>
            <p>If the problem persists, please contact us</p>
            <Link to="/">
              <button>Back to Home</button>
            </Link>
          </>
        );
        toast.error("ERROR! Something went wrong!");
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error.code);
      });
  }, []);

  const appearance = {
    theme: "stripe",
    variables: {
      fontFamily: "Sohne, system-ui, sans-serif",
      fontWeightNormal: "500",
      borderRadius: "8px",
      colorBackground: "#ffffff",
      colorPrimary: "#ffffff",
      colorPrimaryText: "#1A1B25",
      colorText: "white",
      colorTextSecondary: "white",
      colorTextPlaceholder: "#727F96",
      colorIconTab: "white",
      colorLogo: "dark",
    },
    rules: {
      ".Input, .Block": {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        border: "1.5px solid var(--colorPrimary)",
      },
    },
  };

  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className={styles.checkout_section}>
        <Card cardClass={styles.checkout_container}>
          {!clientSecret && <div>{message}</div>}
          {clientSecret && (
            <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
              <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>
          )}
        </Card>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

The following is the component CheckoutForm.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import styles from "./CheckoutForm.module.scss";
import { images } from "../../constants";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectEmail, selectUserID } from "../../redux/slice/authSlice";
import {
  CLEAR_CART,
  selectCartItems,
  selectCartTotalAmount,
} from "../../redux/slice/cartSlice";
import { selectShippingAddress } from "../../redux/slice/checkoutSlice";
import { addDoc, collection, Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase/config";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

const CheckoutForm = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const userID = useSelector(selectUserID);
  const userEmail = useSelector(selectEmail);
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const cartTotalAmount = useSelector(selectCartTotalAmount);
  const shippingAddress = useSelector(selectShippingAddress);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }
  }, [stripe]);

  // Save order to Order History
  const saveOrder = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const date = today.toDateString();
    const time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
    const options = {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "2-digit",
      day: "2-digit",
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      second: "2-digit",
      timeZone: "Europe/London",
    };
    const datetime = today
      .toLocaleString("en-GB", options)
      .replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
    const orderNumber =
      datetime.substring(0, 8) +
      datetime.substring(8, 14) +
      randomNumber.toString();
    const orderConfig = {
      userID,
      userEmail,
      orderNumber: orderNumber,
      orderDate: date,
      orderTime: time,
      orderAmount: cartTotalAmount,
      orderStatus: "Order Placed",
      cartItems,
      shippingAddress,
      createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
    };
    try {
      addDoc(collection(db, "orders"), orderConfig);
      dispatch(CLEAR_CART());
      toast.success("Order saved");

      const templateParams = {
        user_email: userEmail,
        to_name: userEmail,
        order_number: orderNumber,
        message: `Dear Customer, Thank you for shopping at Cyber Frog, your order Number is #${orderNumber}`,
      };

      emailjs
        .send(
          process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
          "template_x2pysu3",
          templateParams,
          "02NEV85HSeVMzUTzB"
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS!", result.status, result.text);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED...", error);
          }
        );

      navigate(`/checkout-success?orderNumber=${orderNumber}`);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("ERROR! Something went wrong");
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMessage(null);

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const confirmPayment = await stripe
      .confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
          return_url: "https://cyber-frog.co.uk/checkout-success",
        },
        redirect: "if_required",
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("confirmPayment response:", result);
        // ok - paymentIntent // bad - error
        if (result.error) {
          toast.error("ERROR! Something went wrong");
          console.log(result.error.message);
          setMessage(result.error.message);
          return;
        }
        if (result.paymentIntent) {
          if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
            setIsLoading(false);
            toast.success("Payment successful");
            saveOrder();
          }
        }
      });

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.payment_main_container}>
        <h2>Payment</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <PaymentElement id={styles["payment-element"]} />
          <button
            disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements}
            id="submit"
            className={styles.button}
          >
            <span id="button-text">
              {isLoading ? (
                <img
                  src={images.spinner}
                  alt="Loading..."
                  style={{ width: "20px" }}
                />
              ) : (
                "Make Payment"
              )}
            </span>
          </button>
          {/* Show any error or success messages */}
          {message && <div className={styles.message}>{message}</div>}
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

and finally, the server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);

const app = express();

// Specify allowed origin
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://cyber-frog.co.uk"
};

// Enable CORS with options
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());

const path = require("path");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("build"))
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"))
  })
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome! This is the backend server of Cyber Frog!");
});

const array = [];

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
  items.map((item) => {
    const { price, cartQuantity } = item;
    const cartItemAmount = price * cartQuantity;
    return array.push(cartItemAmount);
  });
  const totalAmount = array.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  return totalAmount * 100;
};

app.post("/payment", async (req, res) => {
  const { items, shipping, description } = req.body;
  //const { items, shipping, description, receipt_email } = req.body; --> receipt email is not used here because I am using a test account on stripe

  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "gbp",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    description,
    shipping: {
      address: {
        line1: shipping.line1,
        line2: shipping.line2,
        city: shipping.city,
        country: shipping.country,
        postal_code: shipping.postal_code,
      },
      name: shipping.name,
      phone: shipping.phone,
    },
    // receipt_email: customerEmail --> valid only if payment is activated on stripe website
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4242;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

I tried to change the subdomain in the code but nothing is working. If I change the subdomain with loaclhost and run the app with "npm start" then is working. I need this app to work on the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot see your deployment files and environment variables, I assume the problem may be related to the port. I can only see the default port is 4242 since I noticed you accessed it locally using http://localhost:4242. If you are accessing the Node.js server using https://your.domain, you will need to change the listening port to 443, or access with https://your.domain:4242